# Dark mode bug in the "Review|Low Quality Posts" queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, dark-mode

In the "Review|Low Quality Posts" queue, when the post is loading in dark mode, all I see is a white a very bright yellow flash for a few seconds, which against a dark background is very unpleasant to the eyes.

It initially looks worse than in the following screen capture, but due to the animation I could not capture it at its worst:

[image: Argh my eyes]

Comment: This is a known bug, previously reported. I've marked it as a duplicate of the previous bug report.